# Extract data from pipe "|" delimited text file to new excel workbook - worksheet.

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have used the the below code for converting the data from text delimited file to excel workbook, but it stores it on the active workbook , instead of new workbook sheet.

I have 3 text files and i need the data of all these three text files into one new workbook, in three different sheets.

Code snippet below of the macro developed so far-

```
Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
Dim sPath As String, sName As String
sPath = strFileToOpen

sName = "Test.txt"

Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=sPath, _
    Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
    xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False _
    , Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
 Set wkbTemp = xlapp.xlwkbInput
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Set wkbTemp = xlapp.xlextwkbInput -  i need to get this data to new excel workbook - new sheet. for eg - sheet1 , so on and so forth for other two t files, in two other sheets.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways. 
First you can create a new workbook and reference it in the Opentext code:

```
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
    With NewBook
    ..openText
    End With
```

Onother way, a little bit ugly and slow is to copy the sheet from thisworkbook to NewBook. Why this? Because you can improve your understanding of differences between ThisWorkbook and ActiveWorkbook.

Comment: this code will print expected data in sheet1 But how do i get next TXT file data in new worksheet on a same workbook (ie. SHEET2 Of NewBook) and so on  I have 3 Text file, i have to print each txt file data  in separate worksheet of same Workbook  ... thanks in advance

Comment: Vivek it's a little bit tricky the first time but don't worry, try this: `code`

Comment: Sub test()
Set new1 = Workbooks.Add
With newW1
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells(1, 1) = "book1 sheet 1"
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Cells(1, 1) = "book1 sheet 2"
End With

Set new2 = Workbooks.Add
With newW1
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells(1, 1) = "book2 sheet 1"
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Cells(1, 1) = "book2 sheet 2"
End With
'

ThisWorkbook.Activate
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1) = "Now I'm in the master book"


End Sub

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new **Workbook**, and with each **Worksheet**, **Add** a **QueryTable** in the **QueryTables** collection of this **Worksheet** with

> "TEXT;Test.txt"

as first parameter of **Add** for your file type and name, **Range("A1")** as a trivial destination range.

Have a look at the many examples on the Internet how to deal with **QueryTable** Properties. In your case **TextFileOtherDelimiter** is where your pipe **|** should be defined.

Then call **refresh(false)** and **delete** on this QueryTable.

Comment: The best article I found was written by Brian Hart in Core Project. It's here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/136476/Import-a-CSV-File-Into-an-Excel-Workbook-Programma